# Reduce HID time interval

Tags: python, windows-7, usb, hid

I have a Python script that transfers data to/from a USB HID device on a Windows 7 PC. If I start the script it gets normal priority. In this case there are time intervals of about 8ms between transfers on the USB bus, which I monitor using the Free Device Monitoring Studio.
When I set the priority of the Python process to 'High' in the Windows Task Manager, the intervals get reduced to 4..5ms.
Is there a way to further reduce this interval? (Unfortunately the priority of the Python process can't be set to 'Realtime' - system refuses to do so.)

Thanks for any help!
Regards, Gerhard

Comment: What is your accessing method (`DLL`, `System_Class`, `Virtual_Device`)?

Comment: Another point `what is your HID device minimum response time ? `

Comment: The minimum response time of my device is in the range of 1ms. But that's not the problem. Each access attempt is delayed by some milliseconds, for some reason I do not know.

Comment: Concerning the access method: I don't really know. I'm just using an API provided by another department of our company that uses the Python package pywinusb.hid. I don't know any internals of that package, sorry.